# Bind jquery datatable to C# Webmethod

Tags: jquery

i need to create a datatable (jquery) bind to ajax (C# WebMethod)

1-WebMethod return json

```
 public string  GetProjects()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("ProjectData");
        string Conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GPS_TrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conn);

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SP_GetAll_Projects", conn); // / + branch, conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
        conn.Close();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //return ds.GetXml();
        //Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(dt));
        var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,
 Formatting.None,
 new JsonSerializerSettings()
 {
     ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
 });

        return list;
        // return (js.Serialize(dt));
    }
}
```

2- Client Script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTable").dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Query.asmx/GetCars",

            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "url": sSource,
                    // "data": "{'sEcho': '" + aoData[0].value + "'}",
                    "success": function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                        fnCallback(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            },
            "columns": [
       { "data": "Name" } 

            ]

        });
    });
```

3- HTML

```
        <table id="myTable"   width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Name</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
```

4- json Result

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

[{"id":1,"Name":"mh","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null},{"id":2,"Name":"rf","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null}]

4- the current situation 
the alert in the success show the correct data
but the table does not show data my problem is how to tell the datatable that the table column name goes to the data column name
NO Console errors

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var  Table1 = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "Query.asmx/GetCars",
            type: "POST",
            "datatype": "json",
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "Name", "name": "Name" }
        ],
        "bDestroy": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 25,
        "processing": true,
        "searching": false,
        "bSort": false,
    });




 <table id="myTable"   width="100%">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Invalid json Response    Response (    <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"id":1,"Name":"mh","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null},{"id":2,"Name":"rf","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null}]
</string> )

Comment: Please check your JSON format, see this https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Answer (score 0):

if your json response is `[{"id":1,"Name":"mh","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null},{"id":‌​2,"Name":"rf","Start‌​Date":null,"EndDate"‌​:null}]`

change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTable").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Query.asmx/GetCars",

        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": 'json',
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "url": sSource,
                // "data": "{'sEcho': '" + aoData[0].value + "'}",
                "success": function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                    fnCallback(msg.d);
                }
            });
        },
       "columns": [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'Name' },
        { data: 'StartDate' },
        { data: 'EndDate' }]
    });
});
```

Comment: this is the response  Invalid json Response Response ( <string xmlns="tempuri.org/">; [{"id":1,"Name":"mh","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null},{"id":‌​2,"Name":"rf","Start‌​Date":null,"EndDate"‌​:null}] </string> )

Comment: I think the response is json warrped inside XML string tag I sent the whole response

Comment: the alert of the data show but not in the datatable a console error  datatables.min.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at xb (datatables.min.js:57) for(e=c.length;d<e;d++)

Comment: try adding "sAjaxDataProp":"" to datatable properties